# Simplifying error handling in go

Tags: go

In C and similar languages the following shortcuts can be applied to detect an error and stop on first non-zero result

```
(void)(result = dosomething() ||
       result = dosomething() ||
       result = dosomething()
)

if (result == 0 && ...
```

In golang, I can't seem to do that.

For example:

if result = dosomething() ||
   result = dosomething(); result < 0 {
    fmt.Printf("Error occurred\n");
}

C is able to treat integers as a boolean expression when checking for non-zero.

for example I can write

```
if (result = dosomething() || ... )
```

Instead of

```
if ( (result = dosomething()) == 0 || ... )
```

But in go, you can't do that.

I thought I could write:

```
if result = dosomething() == 0 ||
   result = dosomething() == 0; result < 0 {
   fmt.Printf("Error occurred\n");
}
```

But I get an error.

```
syntax error: result = dosomething() || result used as value
```

There has to be a way of chaining these together.  Or in the style of
javascript promises could a `dosomething().doSomething.doSomething.error()` approach be possible?

Any creative solutions to this problem?  I'm really just wanting to avoid
lots of repetitive code where I want to do a whole bunch of things, but if there is an error at any point stop.  Because the error handling logic for each is exactly the same.

Comment: Go is a language that promotes consistency and readability of code.  This reduces the cognitive load of others who have to read your code.  Also, debugging is a lot easier when you know exactly which call failed.

Comment: @eSniff - pollution of the code path with copious amounts of error handling code bloats code and reduces readability.  Generally, you want to get on and write code that follows the normal path and not be too bothered with error handling which is the exception.  Milo's answer below produced a very readable result for me.  It's tidy and easy to understand.

Comment: Bhargav doesn't get notified of your comments here (now deleted) because he never interacted with the question. Only people who have left a comment or edited the associated post can be notified with @ comments. Raising a custom moderator flag (after Milo expanded the answer a bit) was the correct course of action. I have tweaked it a bit more to add explicit attribution and quote formatting, and undeleted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Errors are values](https://blog.golang.org/errors-are-values) on *The Go Blog*. This article, written by Rob Pike, has an interesting and powerful method of handling errors in a group of functions that works very well.

I have used this technique before several times, and it really works.

For reference, the code used for this technique looks like this (copied from the article):

> ```
> // Helper type
> type errWriter struct {
>     w   io.Writer
>     err error
> }
>
> func (ew *errWriter) write(buf []byte) {
>     if ew.err != nil {
>         return
>     }
>     _, ew.err = ew.w.Write(buf)
> }
>
> //Usage:
> ew := &errWriter{w: fd}
> ew.write(p0[a:b])
> ew.write(p1[c:d])
> ew.write(p2[e:f])
> // and so on
> if ew.err != nil {
>     return ew.err
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `slice` and a `for` loop.

https://play.golang.org/p/NJaCliBydA

```
s := []func() error{do1,do2,do3,do4}
for i := range s {
    if err := s[i](); err != nil {
        return err
    }
}
return nil
```

Really though, you probably SHOULD follow the examples in the other answer as they come directly from documentation.

Comment: Ok for bool.  Whatabout for error returned?  I get && not defined on interface.

Comment: @Matt Working on another idea, one sec.

Comment: Thanks, a good solution as well.  I was thinking perhaps a map/slice might work but still learning go.  I think the other answer is cleaner in my case.

Comment: As Milo's answer states, errors are values. Just pointing out that functions are values too!

Comment: @Matt whichever works best. Like I originally said, I am probably not fully understanding your specific use case. Just offering an alternative :)

Comment: In my case, wrapping the systemd-go AddMatch/AddDisjunction calls.  Made more sense to make local wrappers.